# Download a file with springboot resttemplate

Tags: spring-boot

I using this code to download a file:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = recuperaHeaders();
            File file = restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, clientHttpResponse -> {
                File ret = File.createTempFile("download", ".PDF");
                InputStream body = clientHttpResponse.getBody();
                StreamUtils.copy(body, new FileOutputStream(ret));
                return ret;
            });
            return file;
```

but the URL called return an 302 (redirect) looking for some sample alway says that when I use GET the redirect are automatic, but the file always return with size 0, and If I paste the URL in browser works fine

this is my log:

```
2021-08-11 16:40:54.217 DEBUG 2149 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET <<Myurl.....>>
2021-08-11 16:40:54.697 DEBUG 2149 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 302 FOUND
2021-08-11 16:59:14.609 DEBUG 2149 --- [  restartedMain] b.c.l.b.api.BalcaoonlineApiApplication   : File Size: 0
```

if I use an public file just like this (https://www.mds.gov.br/webarquivos/public/NOBSUAS_2012.pdf)  find in google, the download works fine..
and I using the sample from Baeldung site : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file#download-without-resume

Comment: What happens when you make a call to something that doesn’t return 302? Also note that you’re not flushing and closing the stream.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I using this Baeldung sample: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file#download-without-resume

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I update the question